# Facebook acoount login in webview

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to know that is there any way to login my account in `webview` by picking username and password from textfields and load it in `webview`?

Basically I want to make an custom username and password fields. When user put fb name and password on it, it send request to `facebook` with username and password for login in `webview` for use facebook in webview. If username and password is correct then it save on `NSUserDefaults` for next time automatically login.

Please can anyone tell me how I can achieve functionality like this.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. If you enter password on your textfield, and login is successful, security for your user facebook account has been compromised.

Comment: I was thinking same.. @jo3birdtalk

Comment: what you think is there any solution for login in webview by using sdk or graph api??

Comment: www.developers.facebook.com

Comment: @jo3birdtalk is right you can't do it. Because it compromised facebook user account security and Facebook doesn't  allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is actually quit a common thing to do now days.

It is called **social login**, also known as social sign-in, that is a form of single sign-on using existing information from a social networking service such as Facebook, Twitter or Google+.

There is an official way to do this, you can check [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) which guide you step-by-step on how to do this (pretty straight forward).

Basically you need to use `Facebook Login Kit` and they will handle the part where they present a `webView` and asking for credentials. You will get an access token which you can then store in the device (`Keychain` is much preferred from `NSUserDefaults`)

**Note:** The method you described in your question, where you ask the user for username and password store them and inject them to a web view is super not secure and is defiantly not the intent of Facebook API to use.